# Titan and Cassandra debugging and profiling queries

Tags: cassandra, titan

When using the Cassandra backend, is it possible to see the Cassandra queries are being executed from [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.com/titan/), and how long each query takes? Ideally it would output to standard error, or a log file.

This can possibly help optimise the structure of my queries if I can see any inefficiencies in the way Titan is talking to Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to one of the authors of Titan, an acceptable way is to [enable debugging in Cassandra](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/xvOFTKeuR78).

You can do this by uncommenting the DEBUG lines in the cassandra log4j-server.properties file, then restarting Cassandra:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cassandra=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.cassandra.db=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy=DEBUG
```

Comment: I can't figure out where to put these lines/this file.  There is no log4j-server.properties file in the titan 0.3.2 distribution.  Putting them in titan-server-cassandra.properties doesn't seem to work.